# Serve application with non standard index file from different document-root

Tags: lighttpd

I am trying to configure lighttpd to serve an application (let's call it "foo") that is using a non-standard index page (e.g. "`bar.html`") as it's start page from a different document-root than the rest of the pages.

Here is what I have:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www.example.com$" {
    server.document-root = "/usr/local/www/default"

    url.rewrite-once = (  "^/foo/$" => "/baz/bar.html" )
    alias.url += ( "/foo/" => "/usr/local/www/baz/" )
}
```

The idea is that internally, `lighttpd` serves `/usr/local/www/baz/bar.html` when the URL `http://example.com/foo/` is called.

But somehow this does not work. I am not 100% sure what is going wrong but one thing I noticed is that (sometimes?) I get a trailing slash in the URL (something like `http://example.com/foo/bar.html/`).

It seems to be doing something (and actually something not too far from what I am trying to do) but not exactly what I intend.

---

UPDATE: from https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAlias I have learned that no trailing slash should be used on the left hand side in `alias.url` (but should on the right hand side). So I tried

```
alias.url += ( "/foo" => "/usr/local/www/baz/" )
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The `url.rewrite` is changing the URL to "/baz/bar.html" before the `alias.url` is matching against the URL.  Try this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www.example.com$" {
    server.document-root = "/usr/local/www/default"

    url.rewrite-once = (  "^/foo/$" => "/baz/bar.html" )
    alias.url += ( "/baz/" => "/usr/local/www/baz/" )
}
```